# Looking for way to move even lines to the beginning of odd lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to figure out how to move all even lines to the beginning of all odd lines as follows:

before:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

after:

```
BBBAAA
DDDCCC
```

Something I can run on multiple files at once would be great since combining all the files using cat results in a file that is too big to deal with.
Something similar to the following command for doing text swapping so that I can add it to a bash file:

```
  find /directory/. -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldtext/newtext/g' {} \;
```

I have searched but I haven't found something suitable.

To make things easier I can add 'string1' to the beginning of all odd lines and 'string2' to the beginning of all even lines as follows:

```
  before:
  string1AAA
  string2BBB
  string1CCC
  string2DDD

  after:
  string2BBBstring1AAA
  string2DDDstring1CCC
```

Big thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about the idea with the prefix. The script you are looking for is

```
sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/'
```

That is, read the next line with `N`, then change order and remove the newline.

And you can combine this with the `find` as you wrote. Try without option `-i` first to test whether this is what you want.

Comment: As a note: if the file contains an odd number of lines, the behaviour will vary depending on the `sed` implementation and with GNU `sed`, with whether `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment or not.

Comment: If this can happen, `sed '$! N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/'` would be needed if the requirement is to print the last line without a change

Answer (score 1):

***gawk*** solution:

```
for f in /directory/*; do gawk -i inplace '{getline nl; print nl$0}' "$f"; done
```

---

`for f in /directory/*` - for each file in specified path

`gawk -i inplace` - enable *in place* file editing

`getline nl` - read the next record from awk's input into variable `nl` (next line)

`print nl$0` - print the current and the next record swapped

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '1~2 { h; d; }; G; s/\n//'
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ if(NR%2) save = $0; else print $0 save }'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe '$_ = <> . $_; s/\n//'
```

Comment: Or `sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n//p'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That works too, of course.  But if the input file has an odd number of lines, my version is much easier to fix to print the last line unchanged: `sed '1~2 { h; $p; d; }; G; s/\n//'`.

Comment: True (assuming one does want to print that extra line). Mine would have to become `sed -ne '$!{h;n;G;s/\n//;}' -e p`

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: ~` GNU `sed` only?

Comment: @Philippos Yup, as I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

To complete [RomanPrekhrest's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362960/193467), if you have and old version of `gawk` like me that does not support inplace edition, or have the `getline` instruction:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -exec awk 'NR%2!=0{line=$0; next}{print line $0}END{if(NR%2!=0) print line}' {} > /tmp/mytmpfile.txt \; -exec mv /tmp/mytmpfile.txt {} \;
```

Also added something to handle files with an odd number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval "`echo 'NL=qsq' | tr 'qs' '\047\012'`"; # newline
set -- 
while IFS= read -r l; do
   case $# in
      0 ) set -- "$l" ;;
      * ) printf '%s%s\n' "$l" "$1"; set -- ;;
   esac
done < input.data
printf '%s' ${1+"$1$NL"} # to take care of dangling line

awk '{ if ( NR % 2 ) ORS = $0 RS; else print }' input.data

perl -lpe '$_ = (<>.$_) =~ s/\n//r' input.data

sed -ne '
   ${p;d;}
   h;n;G;s/\n//p
' input.data
```

### Result

```
BBBAAA
DDDCCC
```

Comment: Fixed both your concerns.

Comment: `NL='<real-newline>'` is a lot simpler (and doesn't assume an ASCII based system). Or `eval "$(printf "NL='\n'")"`.

Comment: I don't like literal whitespaces in variables as they can be cleaned up by linting or other such tools, and besides this way the intent is clear and it enhances portability.

Comment: Still, `eval "$(printf "NL='\n'")"` is a lot clearer than `eval "\`echo 'NL=qsq' | tr 'qs' '\047\012'\`"`, and you're already using `printf` and `read -r` (which excludes the Bourne shell, the only Bourne-like shell that doesn't support `$(...)`).

Comment: `printf` can very well be non-builtin and we can still be in bourne.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say that `printf` was builtin, just that you already used it, so is already a dependency to your script. `read -r` which you use (and need) won't work in the Bourne shell (unless you want to consider the schily fork, but that one also has `$(...)`).